# A global search box

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way I can search the whole SE for something, not being community specific. In a case where I don't know where my question falls, shouldn't be there a search facility that displays result from all the communities based on the keyword?

Comment: that's where Google's work starts.

Comment: i was looking for something within SE

Comment: that's also Google can, just put your keyword following by site name, like [foo site:stackexchange.com](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=foo+site%3Astackexchange.com)

Answer (score 7):

The [front page of the Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/) has a neat little search field at the top (in the same location as SO's own search field). It launches a Google search with your query but set to return hits only from the sites of the Stack Exchange network.

[Search for `foo`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=foo)

Comment: ok thank you. i missed to see it.. though it looks a lil bit crappy...

Comment: Crappy? How so?